# How to add more multiTooltipTemplate in Chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I make `analytic` for some payment.
And I want to add total payment per day for each data.

This is my `onload` for the `line chart`:

```
window.onload = function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
  multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel + ' - IDR ' + addDot(value) %>",
});

legend(document.getElementById("lineLegend"), data);
```

}

I use `datasetLabel` to show the label name and `addDot` to make the value separate by dot.
But I want to add total so when I hover the total also showing there.